# MapFragment loading but not accessible

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments

I have a fragment that I want to load a Google Map into. I have added a `FragmentMap` and that loads fine. The problem I have is that whenever I try to reference the Map it's coming up as a NULL pointer error.

My layout XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map2"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
     />
```

And the code I've used in my Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    LatLng pp = new LatLng(52.81,1.05);
    MarkerOptions option = new MarkerOptions();
    option.position(pp).title("Home");
    map.addMarker(option);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pp));
}
}
```

The error this generates against, `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference.

My question is, I suspect I maybe referencing the map in the wrong place. Should my code live in the parent activity (so ActivityMain) or in Fragment which contains the map?

Comment: Can you please post your full code + build.gradle and manifest? I understand that your map loads without problem?